# Cert-manager failed to register ACME account

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, cert-manager

I was following this guide on setting up [home Kubernetes lab](https://github.com/PhilipSchmid/k8s-home-lab#cert-manager-installation) and ran into issue while getting the `clusterissuer` to work.

I am getting this error when issuing: `kubectl describe clusterissuer lets-encrypt-dns01-production-do`.

How do I continue to troubleshoot the `x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid?`

```
Name:         lets-encrypt-dns01-production-do
Namespace:
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
API Version:  cert-manager.io/v1
Kind:         ClusterIssuer
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2023-06-25T08:21:39Z
  Generation:          1
  Resource Version:    68732
  UID:                 6bc317ae-d69c-yyy-uuu-xxx
Spec:
  Acme:
    Email:            me@outlook.com
    Preferred Chain:
    Private Key Secret Ref:
      Name:  letsencrypt-prod
    Server:  https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    Solvers:
      dns01:
        Cloudflare:
          API Token Secret Ref:
            Key:   api-token
            Name:  cloudflare-api-token-secret
          Email:   me@outlook.com
Status:
  Acme:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2023-06-25T08:21:49Z
    Message:               Failed to register ACME account: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:41:22Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
    Observed Generation:   1
    Reason:                ErrRegisterACMEAccount
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
Events:
  Type     Reason         Age                    From                         Message
  ----     ------         ----                   ----                         -------
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  76m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T04:29:44Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  71m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T04:34:45Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  66m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T04:39:45Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  61m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T04:44:46Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  15m (x27 over 101m)    cert-manager-clusterissuers  (combined from similar events): Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:29:51Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  13m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:32:44Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  12m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:33:00Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  12m                    cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:33:20Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  12m (x2 over 12m)      cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:33:21Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  12m (x2 over 12m)      cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:33:41Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  9m27s                  cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:36:21Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  9m26s (x2 over 9m26s)  cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:36:22Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
  Warning  ErrInitIssuer  4m26s (x2 over 4m26s)  cert-manager-clusterissuers  Error initializing issuer: Get "https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-06-28T05:41:22Z is after 2022-06-22T20:05:55Z
```

Comment: Hello @Eugene, Feel free to update the status of the question. Let me know the answer below helps to resolve your issue? I am happy to help you if you have any further queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Restarting the Kubernetes API server** may help to resolve your issue.
When you're applying a manifest with **kubectl**, the Kubernetes API server calls the cert-manager webhook over TLS to validate your manifests. So check if **certificates were valid**, and nodes had **proper time and date set**.
**Note:** The cert-manager-webhook uses its own self-signed cert, look at manager-webhook cert expiry.
Check in your environment, make sure the below 3 points are correct, otherwise you may get a warning like `x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid from the client:`

1. The client (presumably kube-apiserver) has the **correct time** (check if the cert is correct then most likely the clock in the pod is wrong. Maybe a misconfiguration or a bad NTP server or something).
2. The client is not overriding the system time when **verifying certs**.
3. The server's cert being presented to the client is valid.

Refer to official Cert Manager [Debugging Guide](https://cert-manager.io/docs/troubleshooting/webhook/#error-x509-certificate-has-expired-or-is-not-yet-valid) & [Troubleshooting common error](https://cert-manager.io/docs/troubleshooting/acme/#common-errors) for more details.

**EDIT :**

**Looks cert was not defined correctly**. Refer to official kubernetes [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#tls) for more details.

> TLS will not work on the default rule because the certificates would
> have to be issued for all the possible sub-domains. Therefore,
> **hosts** in the **tls** section need to explicitly match the **host** in the **rules** section.

Comment: Hello @veera-nagireddy, I have tried checking the 3 points:
  
1.  the date inside kube-apiserver is correct.
2.  hm not sure about how to check this  
3.  the server cert seems correct when checking the slack channel

Comment: Check secrets **acme-key** already exists: there might be a leftover account from a previous issuer that is no longer valid, you should remove the secret so it can be recreated.

Comment: Check this [Workaround](https://github.com/cert-manager/cert-manager/issues/641#issuecomment-399997867) also, which may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Veera! I checked the logs of the ingress-nginx and saw this log: W0704 13:56:42.937635       7 controller.go:1334] Error getting SSL certificate "kube-system/letsencrypt-hubble-ui": local SSL certificate kube-system/letsencrypt-hubble-ui was not found. Using default certificate. 
This default certificate could be the issue!

Comment: Based on your comment, I have edited the answer in the EDIT section. Also refer to similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66469622), which may help to resolve your issue.